# Pass row_array() to Codeigniter view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this controller code:

```
10 $rowArr=$this->m_model->getItemData($itemID);
11 $rowArr=['code'=>'123','desc'=>'456','price'=>'789'];
12 $this->load->view('item_v',$rowArr);
```

In my model I have:

```
$result=$this->db
  ->select('code','desc','price')
  ->where('itemID',$itemID)
  ->get('catalog')
  ->row_array();
return $result;
```

When I run it I get the expected 123, 456, 789 displayed in the 'code', 'desc' and 'price' columns because the second definition of $rowArr gets sent. But when I comment out line 11, allowing the first (intended) definition to take over - I get undefined variable errors for all three in the view.

In my view I'm using:

```
<div>
   <?php
        echo "<div>";
        echo "code: ".$code."<br>";
        echo "desc: ".$desc."<br>";
        echo "price: ".$price."<br>";
        echo "</div>";
   ?>
</div>
```

Since it works OK using the literal array I know the problem must be in the model - no doubt where I attempt to create an array from the db query object. The CI docs seem clear that using the row_array() method should turn the db object into a php array for me. I've tried every variation I could find or think of but nothing works. Can anyone tell me what mistake I'm making? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you get, when you put this code `var_dump($rowArr);` below line 11?

Comment: I get a big NULL when placed below line 10. Or below line 11 when 11 is commented out.

Comment: When line 11 runs then I get the vars listed as expected, 123, 456, 789.

Comment: So your model is not returning anything. Do you have table named **catalog** with columns **itemID, code, desc, price**? And does the column with id passed in `$itemID` exists?

Comment: Yes for all those. Inspecting the $rowArr value with var_dump($rowArr) gives me better visibilty I was using print_r($rowArr) and getting nothing. So, at least I know that the model function called at line 10 is returning null. That's a step forward.

Comment: If the model is returning null then there is no record where itemID=$itemID

Comment: @Banjobum - try put `var_dump($itemId)` on line 11.

Comment: I got to thinking about comment by @DFriend. I have a file called clickRouter.js where I register events - one of which is the button that user clicks to open the view above. That's where I derive the itemID using jq to locate it in the DOM. I somehow deleted part of that line of code. And so it was executing the window.open js for the new page but did not tack the itemID to the end of the URI. I never looked there since I don't remember being in that file for several days.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for getting me to step back and shift my focus.

Comment: catch the error in your model add if(!$result) return $this->db->error(); read the [DB Driver Reference](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/db_driver_reference.html) manual

Answer (score -1):

As you can see from the comments, thanks to @DFriend and @shaggy I found the problem but not where I was so certain it would be. To open the page described as the view, above, the user clicks the tsEditButt in this code:

```
$('.tsEditButt').click(function() {
    var itemID=$(this).closest('.item').attr('id');
    var base_url=$('#hiddenDiv').text(); //'http://localhost/CID17/';
    var url=base_url+'controller_a/index/'+itemID,_blank;
    window.open(url);
```

I had somehow deleted part of the line:

```
 var url=base_url+'controller_a/index/'+itemID,_blank;
```

So it was opening the new page but the itemID was missing and was never passed to the model. As @DFriend said, "If the model is returning null then there is no record where itemID=$itemID". After 2 days of going cross-eyed I think I'll remember this one.